# How to find the number of TCP connections established by an IP address in Java?

Tags: java, networking, tcp, ip-address, spoofing

I'm trying to implement Hop Count Filtering Algorithm. In order to update HCF table to prevent IP Spoofing, I need to update a counter when an IP address has TCP connections in established state in Java.

Comment: Do the connections have to be made to your application or to the machine the app is running on?

Comment: The machine it's running on. It's for an intrusion detection system.

Answer (score 0):

Excecuting the `netstat -at | grep ESTA` you will get all TCP connections established in you machine. To run this command in Java you can use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` as follow

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String s;
        Process p;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("netstat -at | grep ESTA");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            while ((s = br.readLine()) != null){

                // Update here counters if an IP have established a new TCP connection
                System.out.println("line: " + s);
            }

            p.waitFor();
            p.destroy();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.